# Python error using MediaInfo plus wrapper

Tags: python, xml-parsing, mediainfo

I'm currently trying to get the module pymediainfo, which is installed on every machine i try this on and installs with no errors.

For more info on pymediainfo go here (There isn't a lot hence why i'm here): https://pymediainfo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#

Anyway i'm trying to access read and output the xml data in video files for video stats, like bitrate and whatnot, but on every machine but my own home machine, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mvandmake", line 253, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/mvandmake", line 250, in main
    newfile = makefile(todo + "/" + filename + ".mkv")
  File "/usr/bin/mvandmake", line 125, in __init__
    self.media_info = MediaInfo.parse(self.filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymediainfo-1.3.6-py2.7.egg/pymediainfo/__init__.py", line 98, in parse
    xml_dom = MediaInfo.parse_xml_data_into_dom(fp_out.read())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymediainfo-1.3.6-py2.7.egg/pymediainfo/__init__.py", line 85, in parse_xml_data_into_dom
    return BeautifulSoup(xml_data, "xml")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.3.1-py2.7.egg/bs4/__init__.py", line 152, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is missing in terms of dependencies, i don't know if this goes here but it is a python script. If anyone has any ideas or a way for me to check my machine for installed xml parser libraries, that'd be fantastic. Thanks in advance.

- Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in BeautifulSoup not in MediaInfo itself. You need to install the lxml library.

In your python console try:

```
import lxml
```

If this doesn't import correctly try installing lxml with pip

```
pip install lxml
```